# Whats the most efficient way to create an orchestration which updates an Oracle database?

Tags: biztalk

I am creating my first orchestration in Biztalk and am having trouble coming up with an efficient way to update a database (specifically, up to 3 different tables).

The user calls our service with an inbound message matching a schema which contains emplid (unique id) and then a bunch of name-value pairs (see source schema in this picture). The "name" corresponds to a column in a table (e.g. if the name is "employeename" it corresponds to the NAME column of the EMPLOYEE table). The value of course is the new value that the user wants that column to be updated to.

[image]

So they could pass in an update message which only applies to 1 table, 2 tables, or all 3, depending on the fields they want to update for the passed in employee.

I am currently approaching it as 3 separate updates with 3 table adapters (one for each table, one of which is pictured above) but Im having trouble working with the different cases of if they pass in updateValuePairs for all 3 tables, versus only one or only for two tables (the other queries still attempt to run and fail). Am I approaching this right? Or is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: Could you advise which version of BizTalk you are running - it might affect the solution that is proposed.

Comment: Could you update the question to indicate whether you know what key -> table mappings are required? i.e. is there are pre-defined list? Could this list change or is it always fixed? Would you like to change it at a later date?

Comment: biztalk server 2009. The key-> table mappings are explicit and pre-defined (I know them). The list will not change dynamically, its the same per request (unless theres some future enhancement where they add a field, which is possible).

Answer (score 1):

i would try i different way in order to implement cleaner solution,

create a **Store-Procedure** that handle the logic to which table  to go

than you will need only on mapping and one  LOB adapter instead of the 3 you got now

**over view solution**

1.receive input in the orchestration

2.mapping the input to the Stored procedure generated  schema

3.sending the mapped data to the  DB/LOB adapter into the DB

here is a link that can help you (im assuming you use biztalk 2010):

[How to use Oracle Stored Procedure](http://tenalinaga.wordpress.com/2010/11/18/wcf-oracle-apater/)

Comment: Could you expand a little on how Id pass the inbound message to a stored procedure for parsing (or do I parse it before I call the SP?) and then where to capture the return value of the SP? Sorry, I have never used SP before in Biztalk